# Allow webform 2 when webform 1 submitted

Tags: webforms

i'm trying to understand how allow a webform based on sumbission of another.
My Drupal site users have to compile two different forms. The first contains the user's account information and the second one a list of user's equipment. All informations of form 1 and 2 are related to drupal user.
I would like that the second form can be filled only if the user account form is been submitted.
How can i do that?
Thanks

Comment: By “account” do you mean a customer account or a Drupal site account?

Comment: Account means some user's information that i want to collect. Like home address, work address, job, and so on.

Comment: I take @cilefen is asking if that is information associated to a Drupal account on the site, since *user account* usually means *an account created on the site*.

Comment: That's too few information to make a detailed suggestion. This will lead to only opinion-based answers. If that user information is associated with a Drupal user you can simply use access hooks on that second webforms route to check if certain user fields are already filled or still empty. If this is not connected to Drupal users you could let the first webform generate some sort of a token that needs to be present as hidden field in the second form or passed as URL parameter to the second form. Still a million other ways to solve this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sorry guys, yes the user informations in the form 1 are associated with drupal user account. I'll edit right now :)